# How can I write in Tamil language with Google Handwriting Input?

Tags: keyboard, languages, input-methods

OS - Android 4.4.2
Phone - Huawei Honor 6
UI - EmotionUI 2.3

I want to add additional language (Tamil language) under **Settings - Language & Input - Language**, how can I add it?

If I could add Tamil, I could use that in 'Google Handwriting Input'. Or Is there any other way to install Tamil language, so that I could write in Tamil with Google Handwriting Input?

Earlier, I set up 'Swype for Huawei' as default keyboard, long pressed in space bar, selected 'More Languages' 'Download languages', downloaded and installed Tamil, but I could use this only in 'Swype for Huawei' keyboard, not in other 
keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Handwriting Input uses current system language only. However, you can turn off this feature and select the languages you want to use manually.

1. Open **Google Handwriting Input** app
2. On the bottom, tap **Configure languages**
3. Turn off **Use system language**
4. Below that, select any languages you want to use (e.g. **English** and **Tamil**)
5. Tap **Download languages** to download the configured languages to use it.

   [image: Tamil_lang_download]

   <sup>(Click to enlarge screenshot)</sup>
6. Now you can choose Tamil (or any languages you previously selected) for Google Handwriting when inputting on a text box.

***Based on Google Handwriting Input version 1.1.***

Comment: I tried that but Tamil is not in the list and no option available to download.

Comment: I see... Since I'm using different phone, I didn't know if it's based on available languages on the phone. I'm not sure I can help in this case. I think you have to install the Tamil language just like you've thought, but I can't assist that, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewT. There is no prompt to download the language. We have to download it manually by clicking Download Language after Enabling it.

Comment: @Lucky thanks for the edit. At the time I wrote the answer, it automatically prompt to download after selecting the language. Updates happened, and the workflow changed :)